# How to access a nested object in GEOJSON with mapbox

Tags: javascript, json, mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I have a very large geojson that I am reading in via mapbox tile server.  I can get data up to "statistics" but do not know how to access the objects after that.  So how

```
 map.on('click', 'area-polygon', (e) => {
        console.log(e.features[0].properties.statistics);
  });
```

This is the current console.log() output;

```
{"runs":
    {"byActivity":
        {"downhill":
            {"byDifficulty":
                {"easy":
                    {"count":17,
                    "lengthInKm":14.4112,
                    "minElevation":1553.6,
                    "maxElevation":1999.59,
                    "combinedElevationChange":1996.04},
                "advanced":
                    {"count":4,
                    "lengthInKm":2.33805,
                    "minElevation":1645.08,
                    "maxElevation":1936.27,
                    "combinedElevationChange":628.717},
                "intermediate":
                    {"count":11,
                    "lengthInKm":8.24159,
                    "minElevation":1553.6,
                    "maxElevation":2000.42,
                    "combinedElevationChange":1542.16},
                "other":
                    {"count":5,
                    "lengthInKm":2.42858,
                    "minElevation":1595.16,
                    "maxElevation":2005.37,
                    "combinedElevationChange":208.312}
                }
            }
        },
        "minElevation":1553.6,
        "maxElevation":2005.37  
    },
    "lifts":
        {"byType":
            {"chair_lift":
                {"count":3,
                "lengthInKm":3.82236,
                "minElevation":1553.6,
                "maxElevation":1998.59,
                "combinedElevationChange":863.786
                },
            "magic_carpet":
                {"count":1,
                "lengthInKm":0.962681,
                "minElevation":1580.79,
                "maxElevation":1742.16,
                "combinedElevationChange":161.378},
            "gondola":
                {"count":1,
                "lengthInKm":2.07562,
                "minElevation":1580.44,
                "maxElevation":1998.42,
                "combinedElevationChange":417.985}
            },
            "minElevation":1553.6,
            "maxElevation":1998.59
        },
    "maxElevation":1998.59,
    "minElevation":1553.6
}
```

So how would I access the count under easy under byDifficulty etc ?  This doesn't work:

```
e.features[0].properties.statistics.runs.byActivity.downhill.byDifficulty.easy.count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something odd here - if your first log output is correct, your second code would work.

Normally, Mapbox GL JS converts nested objects in GeoJSON into strings.

So you need to do something like:

```
JSON.parse(e.features[0].properties.statistics).runs.byActivity.downhill.byDifficulty.easy.count
```

Comment: Thank you Steve!  You code works but not sure why.  Why parse the begining JSON.parse(e.features[0].properties.statistics) and chain the rest?  Where can I read about that please?  Thank you!!

Comment: Because all of the rest is contained within a string in the `.statistics` property. Once you have parsed it, you can access the other keys as normal.